# Is SSL recommended for node.js behind proxy

Tags: node.js, ssl

Using Apache as proxy, I'm forwarding requests to a specific URL to a node server which is running on localholt.

While the request send to apache is already on `SSL/HTTPS`, I'm wondering if it's preferable/required to also run my node server with `SLL/HTTPS`.

Can someone provide me with some details about this please?

Comment: encryption is used to protect data transfers over Internet but in your case there is no sense to use encryption - you will spend extra CPU resources for nothing if you start encrypting local traffic.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed to know.